# Как вы называете вспомогательные таблицы?

Tags: база-данных, code-style

В базе данных есть две таблицы с разными сущностями, которые относятся друг другу как многие-ко-многим. Есть вспомогательная таблица, в которую пишутся пары первичных ключей для тех самых таблиц.

Какого принципа вы придерживаетесь при наименовании подобных таблиц? *tab1-to-tab2*, *tab1-tab2*, *connector-tab1-tab2*...?

Comment: название должно соответствовать тому, что эта связь хранит. Может оказаться, что две таблицы могут быть соеденены более чем одним способом. Конечно, можно сделать дополнительное поле и указывать тип связи... но нужно будет ещё одну таблицу делать, в которой будут хранится типы.

Comment: @kovadim, я до сего момента полагал, что для связки двух таблиц достаточно двух полей (или трех, если считать еще первичный ключ в самой вспомогательный таблице). Полного ощущения понимания у меня пока нет, поэтому - если вас не затруднит, конечно, - приведите пример.

Comment: вот такой пример с головы:
пусть есть таблица пользователи и таблица группы. Соотвтственно есть таблица, которая указывает, в каких группах присутствуют пользователи. Пусть, просто так добавиться в группу нельзя (нужно пройти модерирование/заплатить/занести). Нужен дополнительное поле, которое будет указывать текущее состояние пользователя в группе.
Либо можно сделать ещё одну таблицу, в которую будут заноситься пользователи, которые хотят добавиться. либо сделать таблицу, в которой будут указаны особые статусы с таблицы связи. Но мне лично нравится вариант с дополнительным полем.